# What's the benefit of using the SQLite Union Virtual Table over creating a view with unions?

Tags: sqlite

The SQLite authors currently implemented a [Union Virtual Table](http://www.sqlite.org/unionvtab.html), but I dont understand the benefit of using that over a simple: `CREATE VIEW foo AS SELECT * FROM A.foo UNION ALL SELECT * FROM B.foo`? Wouldn't the latter preserve index queries on those tables and also allow adding write functionality via triggers?